# Suppress scaladoc implementation warning while creating spring annotation in Java

Tags: scala, sbt, spring-annotations, build.xml, scaladoc

I am trying to create a **Spring annotation** in `Java` as following.

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    MyClass myObj();
}
```

On build, I am getting **warning message** for `standard-scaladoc` as follows:

```
standard-scaladoc:
...
...
[scaladoc-2.12] warning: Implementation restriction: subclassing Classfile does not
[scaladoc-2.12] make your annotation visible at runtime.  If that is what
[scaladoc-2.12] you want, you must write the annotation class in Java.
[scaladoc-2.12] public @interface MyAnnotation {
[scaladoc-2.12]                   ^
[scaladoc-2.12] error: No warnings can be incurred under -Xfatal-warnings.
...
...
```

This is a known bug till Scala 2.12.3 as per [this](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10134) post.

I have used **-Xfatal-warnings** flag in `build.xml` to fail the build in case of any warning.

```
<property name="sources.scalac.extra.args" value="-Xfatal-warnings -feature -deprecation:false"/>
```

Is there any way I can suppress this specific warning without removing **-Xfatal-warnings** flag?

Comment: `build.xml`? What build tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Ant Build tool.